# Expand or Flexible add white bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

**Update**
Added Minimal code
I want to display long text in scrollview.
**Upto redline text is scrollable**
[image]
I tried:
Using flexible  :: **Same Result**
Wraping in Container :: **It makes text full screen and non scrollable**

Code

```
  new Expanded(
          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Text(
             'Very Long text',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
              )),
        ),
```

If i try to increase `flex` property it starts overlapping with upper widget

Thankyou
Full Code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff010409),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          // controller: _uri,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search', prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
            
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.search),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[

        Flexible(
            child: Text(
        'abc',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff58a6ff), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
        )),
        new Expanded(
          flex:2,
          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Text(
            'Big String',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
              )),
        ),
      ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This snipped of code works fine for me*

**UPDATED:**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff010409),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          // controller: _uri,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search', prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.search),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        //Removed Flexible Widget
        Text(
          'abc',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff58a6ff),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 30),
        ),
        new Expanded(
          // flex: 2,  //commented flex here for taking the whole available space.
          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Text(
                """A Long Long String Here...""",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
              )),
        ),
      ])),
    );
  }
}
```

In Above Code Replace **A very Long long String** with your *long Text*

As @AK-23 Pointed out that, Are you sure you need `Expanded` widget above the `SingleChildScrollView` ?

*If Yes then Paste your full Code, So that we can Figure Out the issue.*

**EDITED:**

I have Removed the `Flexible` widget from the `text`, and `commented` the `flex` widget for the `Expanded` widget, and The `code` *started working*.

Comment: yes i tried puting scrollview above expand it display text on whole screen with outpixel expetion and its not scrollable. I updated question with full code

Comment: @user13966865 I have updated the working code, Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the `Text` widget with `Column` worked out for me, like this:

```dart
...
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children <Widget> [
      Text('Very Long text',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
      ),
    ]
)
...
```

I'm not sure whether or not you need the `Expanded` above the `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: above snippet display text on whole screen and it gives overflow Exception

Comment: @user13966865 here is an example of my code on an online dartpad  
https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true
I hope this will be useful to you (you may ignore the yellow underlines)

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: Hi @Akif, thank you for your comment. Here is a new link: https://gist.github.com/arielker/cb1853358694b800f0787d80f2e57381